# Prevent ko click binding on draggable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js, click

I found some questions to stop event propagation when dragging, including the solution I'm trying now:

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scottbeeson/QPndL/3/)

```
$('div').draggable({
    start: function(event, ui) {
        ui.helper.bind("click.prevent",
            function(event) { event.preventDefault(); });
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        setTimeout(function(){ui.helper.unbind("click.prevent");}, 300);
    }
```

This just does not work.  The question does not pertain to KO click bindings.  The only one I found that does pertain, has no accepted answer (the only answer at all is vague and says to try preventDefault()).

So, how can I prevent the click binding when you release the mouse button after dragging an item?

Comment: possible duplicate of [knockout + HTML5 drag and drop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218171/knockout-html5-drag-and-drop)

Comment: What is it exactly that you are trying to achieve? You can prevent the default action on click by doing this in your fiddle: click: function(e) {e.preventDefault();}.

Comment: I think I'm missing something. Releasing the mouse button after a drag should not trigger a click event?

Comment: Correct, releasing the mouse button after dragging should *not* trigger a click event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could solve this with a custom binding:

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.clickUnlessDragged = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
      var $element     = $(element),
          clickHandler = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
          wasDragged   = false,
          mouseupHandler,
          dragstartHandler,
          dragstopHandler;

      mouseupHandler = function mouseupHandler(event) {
          if (!wasDragged) {
              clickHandler(event);
          }
      };

      dragstartHandler = function dragstartHandler() {
          wasDragged = true;
      };

      dragstopHandler = function dragstopHandler() {
          wasDragged = false;
      };

      $element.on('mouseup', mouseupHandler);
      $element.on('dragstart', dragstartHandler);
      $element.on('dragstop', dragstopHandler);

      $element.draggable();

      // clean up after ourselves if KO removes the element
      ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
        $element.off('mouseup', mouseupHandler);
        $element.off('dragstart', dragstartHandler);
        $element.off('dragstop', dragstopHandler);
        $element.draggable("destroy");
      });
  }
};
```

Use it with:

```
<!-- ko foreach: name -->
<div data-bind="text: name, clickUnlessDragged: function() {console.log('clicked')}"></div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

All three event handlers share the same closure, so we are able to use the `wasDragged` flag to communicate whether a drag had started or not.

Dragging stops after the `mouseup` event; since we are binding our own `mouseup` handler first, it runs before `dragstop`.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QPndL/13/).

Comment: Works great, except it doesn't seem to pass the event like the default click binding.  I was using e.ctrlKey to detect CTRL+Clicks.  Is that an easy fix?

Comment: @ScottBeeson two words :) I've updated the mouseupHandler to pass the event along.

Comment: Thanks!  And +1 for understanding the question :)

Comment: Actually, one more thing... I thought I could figure it out but I'm not having much luck.  It also needs to pass the viewModel.  I should have specified all this upfront.  Sorry.

Comment: The function it calls looks like this:  self.select = function (entity, event) { }

Comment: Have you tried changing `clickHandler(event)` in `mouseupHandler` to `clickHandler(bindingContext, event)` or `clickHandler(viewModel, event)`?

Comment: I did try that, the first parameter is still the event and the second is undefined.

Comment: err, crap.  Apparently I had a typo or something.  It's working now!